# Using of animation when repeater update

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

i am developing an update panel.which tracks the visitors and show every update in a repeater.
i bind the repeater with database. and place it inside update panel and with help of timer control,it partially postback in every 5 seconds so hat repeater update in every 5 seconds.
i want when a new record enter in repeater it will show dynamicaly like sliding down.i use javascript and jquery for that but nothing work inside repeater.

if there is any other method to refresh repeater then please tell me

Comment: Did you try anything? Code please.

Comment: i tried it by using jquery and javascript code        <script type="text/javascript">  $.('#btn').click(function ()){    $.("div").slidedown("slow"){   });  });       it works when a text outside repeater apply on it but how to call it in repeater control.and in which event .because i want auto refresh of repeater how can i change the js.

Comment: all i want is to show my update panel like facebook side notification panel when it update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use name of class instead f id f div use like
`$(document).ready(function () {
            $('.FadeIn').click(function () {
                $('.show').('slow');
            });
        });
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".FadeIn").trigger('click')
        });`